# FileInputStream can not open a `relative path` file correctly with specific `user.dir` value

Tags: java, file, maven, fileinputstream

The project use **maven** to build and its file structure as follows.

```
fnlp
├── fnlp-app
├── fnlp-core
├── models
│   └── seg.m
└── tmp
    └── lucene
```

Now, I switched working directory to sub-module `fnlp-app` and set VM OPTIONS
with **`-Duser.dir=$MODULE_DIR$`**.

```
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File("../tmp/lucene"));
```

When used `FSDirectory.open`, it can get an expected result.

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("../models/seg.m"));
```

However, executed above code, it got **java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../models/seg.m (No such file or directory)**

Simple test code snippet and logs.(Thanks @jon-skeet 's suggestion.)

```
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    // Output: /home/xohozu/workbench/git/github/fnlp/fnlp-app

    System.out.println(new File("./models/seg.m").getCanonicalPath());
    // Output: /home/xohozu/workbench/git/github/fnlp/fnlp-app/models/seg.m

    FileInputStream inSteam1 = new FileInputStream(new File("./models/seg.m"));
    // Passed

    FileInputStream inSteam11 = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/xohozu/workbench/git/github/fnlp/fnlp-app/models/seg.m"));
    // Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/xohozu/workbench/git/github/fnlp/fnlp-app/models/seg.m (No such file or directory)

    System.out.println(new File("../models/seg.m").getCanonicalPath());
    // Output: /home/xohozu/workbench/git/github/fnlp/models/seg.m

    FileInputStream inSteam2 = new FileInputStream(new File("../models/seg.m"));
    // Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../models/seg.m (No such file or directory)

    FileInputStream inSteam22 = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/xohozu/workbench/git/github/fnlp/models/seg.m"));
    // Passed
```

Comment: Ignore my now-deleted comment if you saw it. I would suggest you log `new File("../models/seg.m").getCanonicalPath()` to work out what's going on.

Comment: /path/to/fnlp/models/seg.m  it is right.

Comment: Right, and that file *does* exist? If you put that exact output into the string instead of the relative filename does that work? If so, that would be very odd...

Comment: it does exist, instead of `new FileInputStream(new File("../models/seg.m"));`, `new FileInputStream(new File("./models/seg.m"));` passed without exception. But `new File("./models/seg.m").getCanonicalPath()` printed **/path/to/fnlp/fnlp-app/models/seg.m**, it is so wild.

Comment: Oh, I see - I had interpreted your previous comment as a response to my first comment. Please edit your question with the results of logging both `new File("../models/seg.m").getCanonicalPath()` and `new File("./models/seg.m").getCanonicalPath()`

Comment: Right, that's now the *opposite* way round to how your original comment had the logs, which was extremely confusing. So if you put `new FileInputStream("/path/to/fnlp/models/seg.m")` in your code, what happens?

Comment: It run in right way without any exception. Because **/path/to/fnlp/models/seg.m** does real exists.

Comment: In that case, given that `new File("../models/seg.m")` resolves to the right path, it should work fine. Given the confusion you've had in comments before, it sounds like this was a really a typo in your code - if you think otherwise, please try to put together a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. (Just a console app which reads a file... no need for anything complicated.)

Comment: I'm ensure that there is no typos in my codes. Please recheck my question, I updated some description.

Comment: And the sample snippet of `FileInputStream inSteam2 = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/fnlp/models/seg.m"));`? Given the logs you've written out, it sounds like your `seg.m` file is really in `/path/to/fnlp/fnlp-app/models/seg.m`, unlike your diagram. Please double-check this. The chances of you having discovered a bug in Java's file handling are much smaller than the chances of you putting a file in the wrong place, IMO.

Comment: OK, I know your words.So, I re-updated my question with real codes and logs to show you my confusion. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Well that certainly *looks* impossible to me. I'm afraid there's no way I'd be able to help you without a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, so I can reproduce it.

Comment: Hi, I have sent a email to you which contains more details about this problem. Please check it.

Comment: Yes, I've received your email: it didn't include a short but complete program. You should create a short but complete program demonstrating the problem and edit it into your question instead of emailing me.